# OctoberCMS: How to access database tables after they are created?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I need to access one of my database tables in the `boot` method of my plugin. The problem is that the first time that the plugin is installed, in the `boot` method, the tables have not been created yet, because the migration files are yet to be executed. So where is a safe place to access database tables the first time that my plugin is installed? How can I make sure that all migration files have been executed before accessing the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as the following:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('my_plugin_table')) {
    $this->doSomeStuff();
}
```